# How can I get data from firebase by matching the user given inputs with the store data?

Tags: database, if-statement, search, conditional-statements, data-mining

I have entered two or three symptoms for different diseases in firebase. Using the app user will enter his/her own symptoms. The app will predict the disease by matching the user inputs with the data present in firebase.
What simple method can I use for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I haven't written any code. I am trying find the way how to solve. I have mentioned my problem